# Choosing MemoryLimit for Argon2 in PHP

Tags: php, apache, memory, memory-management, libsodium

Libsodium recommends choosing the maximum amount of memory that you are “*guaranteed* to have available” when using the Argon2 hashing function.  My problem is how do we find this out?  From what I understand, since my website is interactive (i.e. uses MySQL, several request pages, etc.), I could run into a variety of situations, like:

1. Having multiple users access the same hashing function page at roughly the same time, overloading the system and running out of physical memory,
2. Having users accessing other pages, whose memory usage add up to produce a similar “crash” as soon as just one user tries using the function,
3. A combination of the two

Obviously the probabilities are rather low of this occurring, much less having so many users using the server at the same time.  However, if I want the strongest hash I can afford, I need to know this at least roughly.  I only have 1gb of RAM in total.

**Are there any memory checks I can put in my PHP scripts to make sure the server doesn’t crash?  Is there nothing I can do?**

(See: https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/content/password_hashing/the_argon2i_function.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about memory exhaustion, allocate some swap space.

You will definitely want to use at least 32 MB of RAM and >= 3 passes. `\Sodium\CRYPTO_PWHASH_*_INTERACTIVE` gives you this minimum threshold.